# It's correct this Exercise Query SQL?

Tags: mysql, database

I have this DB

```
aeroporto(1) <----> (n)volo(n) <----> (1)aereo

AEROPORTO: (pK)id_ap, città, naz, num_pist 

VOLO: (pk)id_volo, data, (fk)id_part, oraPart, (fk)id_arr, oraArr, (fk)tipoAereo 

AEREO: (pk)id_aereo, qta_merci, num_pass, cod_aereo
```

/ * French cities from which more than twenty direct flights to Italy leave * /

```
select a.citta

from volo as v, aereoporto as a, aereoporto as b

where a.id_ap = v.id_part and b.id_ap = v.id_arr and
a.nazione != b.nazione and a.nazione = 'francia' and count(b.citta = 'italia') > 20 ;
```

It's correct?

Sorry for my poor english.

Comment: Kindly add some sample data - explaining the meaning of relevant columns and expected output

Comment: "Sorry for my poor english." so you expected that we understand the italian table and column names?

Comment: So by "flight" do you mean the id_aereo for a specific plane or just a city regardless of plan had more than 20 id_Volo's to italia?  and 20 flights ever?  or 20 per month 20 per year?  question seems a bit open ended given normal flight operations.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return the city name of all cities leaving 'francia' and arriving in 'italia' having a count of flights > 20.

```
SELECT a.citta
FROM volo as v 
INNER JOIN aereoporto as a 
   on a.id_ap = v.id_part
INNER JOIN aereoporto as b  
   on b.id_ap = v.id_arr 
WHERE a.nazione = 'francia'
  and b.nazione = 'italia'
GROUP BY a.citta
HAVING count(v.id_volo) > 20 ;
```

`GROUP BY` allows us to group like cities together from 'francia' and the having clause lets us count the flights and ensure we only show cities having more than 20 flights.

However, ***this does assume that a citta is not duplicated per naz***.  For example: if the the same named city existed in different regions within francia; then we would have a problem.   So if there were a `Paris Brittany` and a `Paris Île-de-France` and both had airports going to itally; then the `a.citta` for `Paris` would be the count of both Paris cities; which may not be the desired results. Without a unique identifier which describes `a.citta` on which we group this problem could persist.  So maybe we need to group by `a.citta` and `a.id_ap` and display both in the select so the user knows "Which airport' we're talking about.  Alternatively; I believe each airport is assigned a code defining it specifically; if that were tracked as part of the airport information; we could group on it and avoid the a.id_ap.  City alone isn't enough to make a record unique.

Example:

```
SELECT a.citta, a.id_ap 
FROM volo as v 
INNER JOIN aereoporto as a 
   on a.id_ap = v.id_part
INNER JOIN aereoporto as b  
   on b.id_ap = v.id_arr 
WHERE a.nazione = 'francia'
  and b.nazione = 'italia'
GROUP BY a.citta, a.id_ap 
HAVING count(v.id_volo) > 20 ;
```

I don't like using cross joins in the from clause which is the `,` notation in the from does.  This style of join is from the 1980's and should be given up in favor of the explicit syntax of `inner`, `left`, `right`, `full outer` and `cross join`.

My reasoning for this is the FROM clause should define the tables being used and how they relate in most cases.  The where clause should be used to limit the data being returned; mixing the two comes at a cost of confusion and more difficult maintenance long term.  The only exception to this rule is outer join which may need to limit the data as part of the join to maintain the integrity of the outer join.

***To address comment:***
Something like this may work: if the total count of flights from a cities airport matches the count of arrivals coming from italia and destinations to italia then all flights are internal/domestic; otherwise do not show that airport. So the having clause like the where, acts as the filter to exclude cities with flights arriving from or departing to other countries. This approach is a bit more ambiguous on what it's doing but from a performance standpoint it should operate better than an in, not exists, or subqueries would given proper indexes on fields.

```
SELECT a.citta, a.id_ap
FROM volo as v 
INNER JOIN aereoporto as a 
   on a.id_ap = v.id_part
INNER JOIN aereoporto as b  
   on b.id_ap = v.id_arr 
GROUP BY a.citta, a.id_ap 
HAVING count(v.id_volo) =  sum(case when a.nazione = 'italia' then 1 else 0 end as ItalianArrivals)
   and count(v.id_volo) =  sum(case when b.nazione = 'italia' then 1 else 0 end as ItalianDepartures);
```

Given the ambiguity of the above, maintenance may be a bit harder for the next person so by using an explicit not exists once for arrivals and once for departures you can achieve the same results; but I do not believe it would be as optimal in performance... However, it too would achieve the proper results.  I prefer `not exists` over `not in` when dealing with a data set that can grow in size to over 50 values.  Since the query relates to a data set that looks like it would continue to grow, not exists seems like the 2nd best choice over the not in; with the having I believe being better performance on the larger datasets.

Comment: Thanks :) 
and if I want Italian airports that only have internal flights? 

Can I use the not in or not exist or the outer join?

Comment: There's a few ways to address your comment; but I prefer simply modifying the above query to use conditional aggregation and check to see if the total count of flights out of an airport matches the sum of Italian destinations and Italian arrivals. I may have something off in the logic and don't feel up to generating sample data needed to test.   (See updated answer)

Answer (score 0):

I tried hardly to figure out your example and what is the exact output you are trying to retrieve and I think the below shall help you.

```
SELECT a.citta
FROM aereoporto as a, volo as v
WHERE a.id_ap = v.id_part AND a.nazione = 'francia'
GROUP BY a.citta having count(*) > 20 ;
```

**Mockup Data**

**aereoporto**

```
id_ap     citta     nazione
  1       rome      italia
  2       milan     italia
  3       paris     francia
  4       bordeaux  francia
```

**volo**

```
id_volo data    id_part oraPart id_arr  oraArr  tipoAereo
1       NULL       3    NULL       1    NULL    NULL
2       NULL       3    NULL       1    NULL    NULL
3       NULL       3    NULL       2    NULL    NULL
4       NULL       4    NULL       2    NULL    NULL
5       NULL       4    NULL       1    NULL    NULL
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: I agree with you totally marc but actually i was altering Benix code.